# What is this parameter that has a colon in C# called?

Tags: c#, syntax

I encountered something I've never seen before in C# (at least I don't recognize it anyways)...it's got me feeling pretty dumb at the moment.

I downloaded Dapper, which is awesome by the way, and was making my first query with a stored procedure.

```
connection.Query<MyObject>("[dbo].[sp_MyStoredProc]", new
{
    Name = keywords
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The intellisense method signature says this should be an `IDbTransaction`. Is this some type of shorthand that converts:

```
commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

into an `IDbTransaction`?

### Questions

1. What is this called syntax called?
2. What is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: named parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called **named arguments**. See MSDN article [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> Named arguments free you from the need to remember or to look up the
>   order of parameters in the parameter lists of called methods. The
>   parameter for each argument can be specified by parameter name.

Query method of Dapper has many parameters with default values (timeout, commandType etc). With this syntax you can specify only some of them *without* specifying others.

Comment: Well, my ignorance is confirmed! Now knowing the proper name, this is relatively easy to find information on. Hah! Thanks for this informative answer.

Comment: @crush yep, that's a nice feature. Without it you would need to specify other positional arguments which go before command type - transaction and timeout

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Named parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), the query method has a `commandType` parameter which is being specified.

If you define a method like:

```
public static void SomeMethod(string arg1, int arg2)
{
}
```

you can specify the parameters by name e.g.

```
SomeMethod(arg1: "Some string", arg2: 3);
```

You can also specify them out of order:

```
SomeMethod(arg2: 3, arg1: "Some string");
```

One benefit of specifying parameters by name is when their meaning is not obvious by their position e.g. in `Regex.Match`:

```
var match = Regex.Match(@"^\d+$", "1234");    //wrong
var match = Regex.Match(pattern: @"^\d+$", input: "1234");
```

Comment: Is that to say that I could pass them in a different order? What's the benefit of specifying them by name?

Comment: @crush Yes, I believe you can then change the order.